# How do I statically render the first few pages at build time and the rest in real time in Nextjs?

Tags: next.js, pagination, server-side-rendering, nextjs-dynamic-routing, nextjs-redirects

There's a requirement wherein I'm supposed to render a few paginated pages. The problem is, I need to render the first 3 pages during build time and the remaining in real time, i.e if a user clicks on page 4, it should then fetch the data for page 4, but for the first 3, the data needs to be fetched prior, i.e during build time itself.

How do I achieve this in nextjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this with https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-paths

You would need the path of the first 3 pages, and pass those with `getStaticPaths` and leave the rest out.

This will generate the first 3 pages on build, and dynamically build the rest when the user visits the page.

Comment: Thanks! This did work. I'm quite new to Next.js. I have a follow-up question on this, where do I need to make the API call for the rest of the pages? For the first 3, I'm making the API call inside getStaticProps() and passing the result as a parameter to the main function. Using getStaticPaths(), I have passed the paths of the first 3 pages and it works fine. But for the rest, how do I make the API call?